# Opinion! Creating Template filters to work with class instance in templates, this works, wondering the most "django" optimal way?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Accessing class methods in templates, this works but was wondering if their was a better way?

someclass

```py
class Something():
    somevar = None
    def __init__(self, somevar):
        self.somevar = somevar
    
    def set_somevar(self, newvar):
        self.somevar = newvar
    
    def set_weird_and_somevar(self, weird, somevar):
        self.weird = weird
        self.somevar = somevar
    
    def get_tag(self, tag):
```

templateTag

```py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def class_get_method(value, method):
    f = method.split('.')
    method = f[0]
    del f[0]
    p = getattr(value, method)
    if f:
        return p(*f)
    else:
        return p()
```

in template, lets say content is a class instance

```html
{{content|class_get_method:'set_weird_and_somevar.wenday_adams.nothervar'}}
```

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

```
class Something():
    somevar = None
    def __init__(self, somevar):
        self.somevar = somevar
```

Yikes!

Don't do that.

The Turing machine you describe has well-defined semantics.
But python engineers don't write such code,
because it leads to maintenance headaches.

Python is all about namespaces.

There is a global namespace, which `Something` is in.

There is a class namespace which,
ever since the `Something` class was defined (at parse time)
has a `somevar` attribute with value `None`.

Later on, at run time, we create a pair of objects
with `self.somevar` values of `1` and `2`.
But the class attribute is still `None`.

This is perfectly well defined.
The machine won't become confused.
But you or future maintenance engineers very likely will.

Choose a different name for the class attribute, please.
Reference it as `Something.somevar`, or as `cls.somevar`
from within a `@classmethod`.

---

Notice that class attribute `somevar` can be initialized
as a mutable data structure, such as a dict.
And then both classmethods and ordinary methods can mutate it.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate it, but i thought as we got older we fked the new engineers lol